# How to process Akka stream based on some condition?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Suppose there is a stream of some files to be processed and only a specific file should be processed(consumed) when a condition is met.

i.e. Only if the stream contains a file named "aaa", process a file named "bbb"

```
SomeFile(name: String)
```

What would be the correct(recommended) way to do this?

Comment: What is the type of your stream? can you give a signature? Sounds like Akka HTTP stream ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: yes, it is Akka stream. 
`akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[SomeFile, NotUsed]`

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that you could filter your stream for cheap if it would have filenames only and be relatively short. However, if it's a filename together with a bytestream like something you see on file upload then you have to keep consuming the whole stream discarding files you don't need.

Comment: Will the file named "bbb" come after the file named "aaa"? You could use StatefulMapConcat to keep track of when something has come in. Or you could use it to buffer all of the files coming in and release them when you find the matching one... but be careful of running out of memory

Comment: I guess the general answer might be: filter down your stream to 0-2 elements, materialize it after that and then check if aaa exists. Perhaps the question is a bit vague. I'm not quite sure what exactly the problem is. Best practice? Optimal performance, etc. Can you have/split this into two streams: one that gives filenames and the other that gives file bytes?

Comment: @JasonCarreira The order of files is not guaranteed.

Comment: @yǝsʞǝla I would like to know some general approach to this. It might not be the best solution, but could be a common approach to get this kind of problem done.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's an example. Be careful about building up too big a buffer here before the trigger hits

```
class FileFinder {

  def matchFiles(triggerName: String,
                 matchName: String): Flow[SomeFile, SomeFile, NotUsed] =
    Flow[SomeFile].statefulMapConcat(
      statefulMatcher(matches(triggerName), matches(matchName)))

  private def matches(matchName: String): SomeFile => Boolean = {
    case SomeFile(name) if name == matchName => true
    case _                                   => false
  }

  private def statefulMatcher(
      triggerFilter: => SomeFile => Boolean,
      sendFilter: SomeFile => Boolean): () => SomeFile => List[SomeFile] = {
    var found = false
    var sendFiles: List[SomeFile] = Nil
    () => file: SomeFile =>
      {
        file match {
          case f if triggerFilter(f) =>
            found = true
            val send = sendFiles
            sendFiles = Nil
            send
          case f if sendFilter(f) =>
            if (found)
              List(f)
            else {
              sendFiles = f :: sendFiles
              Nil
            }
          case _ => Nil
        }
      }
  }
}

object FileFinder extends FileFinder {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("finder")
    implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val executor: ExecutionContextExecutor =
      materializer.executionContext
    implicit val loggingAdapter: LoggingAdapter = system.log

    val files = List(SomeFile("aaa"), SomeFile("bbb"), SomeFile("aaa"))
    Source(files)
      .via(matchFiles("bbb", "aaa"))
      .runForeach(println(_))
      .andThen({
        case Success(_) =>
          println("Success")
          system.terminate()
        case Failure(ex) =>
          loggingAdapter.error("Shouldn't happen...", ex)
          system.terminate()
      })
  }

}

case class SomeFile(name: String)
```